# randomly duplicate a canvas using key up event

Tags: html, canvas

let me try to explain what I'm trying to do. I have a canvas size 500 x 500 and I drew a triangle. Using a key up event is possible to duplicate this triangle randomly inside the canvas?

So far a I have this:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Canvas</title>
   <script src="canvas.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
</head>
<body onload="setUp()">
    <h1>Triangle</h1>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" height="500" width="500" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>

    <br>
    <button type="button" id="resetbtt" name="button">Reset</button>

</body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
let canvas;
let ctx;
let dx = 10;
let dy = 10;
let x = 250;
let y = 250;
let WIDTH, HEIGHT = 500;


function setUp(){
   canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
   ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
   let resetbtt = document.getElementById('resetbtt');
   drawTriangle();
}

function drawTriangle(){

    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(x,y)
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(-15, 15);
    ctx.lineTo(15, 15);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
```

I dont know how to set the duplicates

Comment: please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and let us know where you are stuck.

Comment: Ok, I wrote what I have so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let canvas;
let ctx;
let dx = 10;
let dy = 10;
let WIDTH, HEIGHT = 500;


function setUp() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  let resetbtt = document.getElementById('resetbtt');
  drawTriangle(250, 250);
}
//little transfor your function - add parameters X and Y - this is start to draw
function drawTriangle(x, y) {

  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.translate(x, y);
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(-15, 15);
  ctx.lineTo(15, 15);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();

}
//this small function get random int number
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
//add event Listener when press key
document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {//32 is keyCode space
    var x = getRandomArbitrary(20, 450),
      y = getRandomArbitrary(20, 450);
    drawTriangle(x, y);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Canvas</title>
</head>

<body onload="setUp()">
  <h1>Triangle</h1>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" height="500" width="500" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>

  <br>
  <button type="button" id="resetbtt" name="button">Reset</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Halyna, thanks for your help. But the triangle is duplicate always in the center when click. And how it would be if you change the click event for a keyup event for space bar?

Comment: I understand you correctly, the triangle must be draw again always in center canvas when user press a space?

Comment: @AndersonTrugilio I update solution. Is it what you want?

Comment: Hi Halyna. What I need is when press the space bar the triangle should appear randomly inside the canvas, any place inside the canvas

Comment: @AndersonTrugilio, Hi! just could not imagine where such a situation might arise :) I edit solution.

Comment: Hi Halyna! When I press the space bar keep drawing in the center, is not drawing randomly inside the canvas.